# Changing java.security on bundled jre - PCI compliance

Tags: java, pci-compliance, pci-dss

We are bundling jre along with our product and want to change java.security to disable TLSv1.0 (For PCI compliance).

I want to check if doing that violates the license and if there are other products who does the same. Java license is unclear on this topic. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html

Comment: If your product does not use (and cannot be configured to use) TLSv1 what is the need for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a legal question instead of programming.

Comment: @AlexK. Java bydefault allows TLSv1.0 and we want to disable that.

Comment: So long as the calling code does not use TLS1 its hard to see why you care. My PCI apps use .Net which also supports TLS1, I don't try to modify the framework I just make sure I use TLS1.2.

Comment: @Henry  A lot of programming can be avoided (Figuring out all areas of ssl usage and programmatically controlling the protocols and ciphers) if this approach is valid.

Comment: @AlexK. The calling app's are not in our control. eg:  java based https webserver.

Comment: @AtulSoman sure, but the question "is it allowed" is better answered by a lawer than by a programmer.

Comment: @Henry, my intend is to see if this is tried anywhere else. I think this question is going to be more relevant because of the mandate of adoption of PCI compliance in the next year onward.